# Recode the value of a variable given the value of another one

Tags: r, variables, dataset, recode

I am using a dataset in which there is a mistake in the way the answers for a given country are coded. Let's call my first variable `my.data$country_year` and the second one `my.data$attitude`. A table of the two gives the following output:

```
table(my.data$country_year, my.data$attitude)

       (1) Very Suitable (2) Suitable (3) Somewhat Suitable (4) Not Suitable                      
Yemen.2006    101            142             1192                       0
Lebanon.2007   13           14                    60                  1063
Yemen.2007       49          113                   122                  248
Palestine.2008    131          653                   387                2093
```

The table in question has a lot of countries which I omitted in this example.What I want to do is to ask R to do the following in my original dataset while keeping the observations for all other countries:

for my.data$country="Yemen.2006" & my.data$attitude="(3) Somewhat Suitable", "(4) Not Suitable.

for my.data$country="Yemen.2006" & my.data$attitude="(2) Suitable", "(3) Somewhat Suitable"

In other words, I would like to move to the right the second and third values of the attitude variable for the survey conducted in Yemen in 2006, without creating a new variable. I would like the result to be the following

```
 (1) Very Suitable (2) Suitable (3) Somewhat Suitable (4) Not Suitable                      
Yemen.2006    101            0                   142                 1192                       
Lebanon.2007   13            14                    60                  1063
Yemen.2007       49          113                   122                  248
Palestine.2008    131          653                   387                2093
```

Comment: If you assign `tbl <- table(.)` just do `tbl[1, 2:4] <- tbl[1, c(4, 2, 3)]`.

Comment: Have you tried `within(mydata, { attitude[country=="Yemen.2007" & attitude=="(3)"] <- "(4)" })`, similarly for other countries? (Make sure you move 3 to 4 before 2 to 3, otherwise you'll lose all the 2s.)

Comment: Hello Rui, the suggestion you suggest works but only for a table. I would like to reorder the factor variable attitude according to the factor variable country=Yemen 2006, as per my examples. Do you know of a way to do what you suggest with a dataset?

Comment: Hello r2evans, your solution gets at the logic of my problem properly but R does not accept it when entered. It spits out errors as follows:

    Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nl, value = list(attitude= c(NA, NA,  : 
      duplicate subscripts for columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thank you everybody, I based myself on your answers in order to find the solution. I created a subset of my.data with less variables and this time the within function worked without errors. Only it's r2evans' script that worked best, as follows

```
my.data2 <- within(my.data2, {attitude[country_year=="Yemen.2006" & 
attitude=="(3) Somewhat Suitable"] <- "(4) Not Suitable At All" })

my.data2 <- within(my.data2, {attitude[country_year=="Yemen.2006" & 
attitude=="(2) Suitable"] <- "(3) Somewhat Suitable" })
```

Cheers and thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that attitude is a factor.  In that case, we can just do

```
levels(my.data$attitude) <- levels(my.data$attitude)[c(1, 4, 2, 3)]
```

If it's not already a factor just make it one (at least temporarily):

```
my.data$attitude <- factor(my.data$attitude)
levels(my.data$attitude) <- levels(my.data$attitude)[c(1, 4, 2, 3)]
my.data$attitude <- as.character(my.data$attitude)
```

**Update for only** `Yemen.2006`
Again, assume attitude is a factor:

```
new_value_index <- c(1, 4, 2, 3)
my.data <- within(my.data, {
  attitude[country == "Yemen.2006"] <- levels(attitude)[new_value_index[attitude[country == "Yemen.2006]]] )
})
```

Comment: Hello Melissa, Thanks for your comments but I do not want to switch levels for the whole attitude variable, only for the observations pertaining to Yemen 2006 (as per the example I provided). It seems like your suggestion switches around the levels for attitude for all country_year observations, correct?

Comment: Thanks a ton Melissa, but I am getting an error message similar to what I got for r2evans' suggestion. Both of you suggested using the "within" command, but I end up getting the following error for both suggested fixes:

     Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, nl, value = list(attitude= c(NA, NA, : 
     duplicate subscripts for columns

Let me also clarify that my two variables are indeed factors.

Comment: We will probably need a reproducible example in order to figure out those errors.  ``within`` is a nice command that lets you work within a data frame - notice that I can write ``country`` instead of ``my.data$country``.  It returns a data frame with any newly defined variables as new elements of the data frame - so they had better be the same length as before!.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has mentioned that

> The table in question has a lot of countries which I omitted in this example.

In case of a large table and only a few rows to update, I suggest to use `data.table` which updates *by reference* only the affected rows without copying the whole data object.

There are two approaches: one is to *select and replace*, the other uses an *update join* with a lookup table.

#### Select and replace

This is similar to [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49784352/3817004) but in `data.table` syntax:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my.data)[country_year == "Yemen.2006" & attitude == "(3) Somewhat Suitable", 
        attitude := "(4) Not Suitable"]
my.data[country_year == "Yemen.2006" & attitude == "(2) Suitable", 
        attitude := "(3) Somewhat Suitable"]
```

Note that `my.data` is modified *in place*, so it is not necessary to assign the result to another dataframe. The result can be verified by either

```
dcast(my.data, country_year ~ attitude)
```

or

```
table(my.data$country_year, my.data$attitude)
```

> ```
>                  (1) Very Suitable (2) Suitable (3) Somewhat Suitable (4) Not Suitable
>   Yemen.2006                   101            0                   142             1192
>   Lebanon.2007                  13           14                    60             1063
>   Yemen.2007                    49          113                   122              248
>   Palestine.2008               131          653                   387             2093
> ```

#### Update join

Here, a `lookup` table is created beforehand which is then used in a join to update the matching rows of `my.data` only:

```
library(data.table)
lookup <- data.table(
  country_year = "Yemen.2006", 
  attitude.old = c("(2) Suitable", "(3) Somewhat Suitable"),
  attitude.new = c("(3) Somewhat Suitable", "(4) Not Suitable"))
setDT(my.data)[lookup, on = .(country_year, attitude == attitude.old), 
  attitude := attitude.new][]
```

The result is the same as shown above

#### Reproducible data

In order to test above solutions I have reconstructed `my.data` from the given output of `table(...)`. Note that `my.data` is in long format which requires to `melt()` the sample table and to replicate the rows as many times as given by the counts:

```
DT_wide <- fread(
  "country_year, (1) Very Suitable, (2) Suitable, (3) Somewhat Suitable, (4) Not Suitable
Yemen.2006,    101,            142,             1192,                       0
  Lebanon.2007,   13,           14 ,                   60,                  1063
  Yemen.2007   ,    49,          113,                   122,                  248
  Palestine.2008,    131,          653,                   387,                2093")
DT_wide[, country_year := forcats::fct_inorder(country_year)]
my.data <- melt(DT_wide, id = "country_year", variable.name = "attitude")[
  rep(1:.N, value)][, value := NULL][]

my.data
```

> ```
>         country_year          attitude
>    1:     Yemen.2006 (1) Very Suitable
>    2:     Yemen.2006 (1) Very Suitable
>    3:     Yemen.2006 (1) Very Suitable
>    4:     Yemen.2006 (1) Very Suitable
>    5:     Yemen.2006 (1) Very Suitable
>   ---                                 
> 6377: Palestine.2008  (4) Not Suitable
> 6378: Palestine.2008  (4) Not Suitable
> 6379: Palestine.2008  (4) Not Suitable
> 6380: Palestine.2008  (4) Not Suitable
> 6381: Palestine.2008  (4) Not Suitable
> ```